# Android checkbox select all not selecting all childs

Tags: android, checkbox, scrollview

I am developing an android app, in which there is a custom list view with text view and check box is there. In this listview contact list of mobile will get displayed, now I need to add a select all checkbox and when it is checked all check boxes of conatcts needs to select. I wrote code for that but what happening is when I am selecting checkbox of select all... current view of contacts is getting selcting and the contacts in bottom scrollview is not getting selected. I am giving the code below, please check it and help me to do the changes.

```
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsView);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
switch(view.getId()) {
      case R.id.chkSelectAll:
          if (checked)
          {
              Toast.makeText(MyList.this, "Checked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              for(int i=0; i<lv.getChildCount();i++)

              {
                  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.selected);
                  cb.setChecked(true);
              }
          }

          else
          {
              Toast.makeText(MyList.this, "Not Checked.this time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              for(int i=0; i<lv.getChildCount();i++)
              {
                  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.selected);
                  cb.setChecked(false);
              }
          }
          break;

    }
    }
```

Comment: what is lv??? please add proper code

Comment: Please check..edited

Comment: try to set boolean for that

Comment: check my answer

Comment: add ma.notifydatasetchange after for loop

Comment: is that solved or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this way this is exactly what you looking for

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    /** String array used as the datasource for the ArrayAdapter of the listview **/
    String[] countries = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "Bangladesh",
        "China",
        "Afghanistan"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Defining array adapter to store items for the listview **/
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

        /** Setting the arrayadapter for this listview  **/
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

        /** Defining checkbox click event listener **/
        OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v;
                int itemCount = getListView().getCount();
                for(int i=0 ; i < itemCount ; i++){
                    getListView().setItemChecked(i, chk.isChecked());
                }
            }
        };

        /** Defining click event listener for the listitem checkbox */
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);
            int checkedItemCount = getCheckedItemCount();

            if(getListView().getCount()==checkedItemCount)
                chk.setChecked(true);
            else
                chk.setChecked(false);
            }
        };

        /** Getting reference to checkbox available in the main.xml layout */
        CheckBox chkAll =  ( CheckBox ) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);

        /** Setting a click listener for the checkbox **/
        chkAll.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        /** Setting a click listener for the listitem checkbox **/
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    }

    /**
    *
    * Returns the number of checked items
    */
    private int getCheckedItemCount(){
        int cnt = 0;
        SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
        int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

        for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++){
            if(positions.get(i))
                cnt++;
        }
    return cnt;
    }
}
```

For more see this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-checkall-and-uncheckall-for-a-listview-in-android/

http://aboutyusata.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-make-listview-with-checkbox-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check the checkboxes via "getChildAt(i)" because the ListView only renders the rows which are on the screen.

You need to make the adapter do the work:

In MyAdapter add something like:

```
public void selectAll() {
    for (Contact c : this.contacts) {
        c.setSelected(true);
    }
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I don't now how you datamodel is structured but I hope this will give you the right direction.